# Reverse Engineering a binary file with no extension

Tags: radare2

Is it possible to reverse engineer a binary file with no extension?

For example this file:

https://github.com/commaai/openpilot/tree/master/selfdrive/visiond

I have tried radare2 but it throws out the following error, so I am assuming it's a ARM binary:

unimplemented elf reloc_convert for arm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to reverse engineer a binary with no extension. Consider a "reversible" binary with an extension. Remove the extension. Is the binary itself any different than it was before? Extensions have no significance in this context. Although I'm not sure, your error appears to indicate a radare shortcoming.

```
$ file visiond 
visiond: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker64, stripped
```

Answer (score 0):

I can open that file in R2 with out any errors. Make sure you have the latest (from git) version of radare2, and then try again